# New to terminal command line; trying to run '$ gem install iStats'

Tags: terminal

I am a Windows user and just got the new MacBook Pro with the latest OS updates. I wanted to install one tool in which it was mentioned to install run
`$ gem install iStats`

which gives me an error

```
$ ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
nitin_mac@Nitins-MBP ~ %
```

I am not sure how to get permission; if I run `$ su`, it asks for a password even if I am entering the correct one it still gives me an error

```
$ su:sorry

nitin_mac@Nitins-MBP ~ % su
Password:
su: Sorry
```

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is if something tells you to use su it is probably wrong unless you fully understand why you are using it.

In this case ruby is set up so that gems are written to a directory /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 that needs root permissions to write to. Thus you get the first error.

You can install the gem by running

```
sudo gem install iStats
```

You will be prompted for your own password (su prompts you for the password of the user you are changing to which without any other arguments is root - which on macOS by default does not have one and you cannot use root. Which explains why you could not provide the password for su as you don't know it.)

I would note that if you are doing much Ruby work you should look at [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or similar to allow gems to be installed without sudo and allow different gems for different projects.

Comment: Usually if the instructions tell you to use `sudo`, they're probably wrong (again) if you don't understand why.  A decent reference is https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/the-definitive-guide-to-installing-ruby-gems-on-a-mac/

Comment: In this case sudo is correct as /Library/Ruby is not a user specific path - but for all users on the path (@MarcWilson  Your comment could be read in a couple of ways if you are saying I should say use su or sudo - or if you are saying sudo is wrong here)

Comment: The path doesn't have anything to do with whether or not `sudo` is the correct thing to use.  I'm saying that you should not be installing into system paths.  There is no reason to.  You should not depend on the system Ruby even being there for much longer.

Comment: @MarcWilson So what is the correct way to install Ruby gems?

Comment: Hence the link I provided, which provides good detail.